# C++ program with Allegro 5 display problems in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, allegro5

I'm trying to create a simple window with text appearing in it.

I'm using allegro 5.1 and Xcode 5.1

When I run it the window shows up, but it doesn't display anything, it's just blank. And it doesn't quit the program automatically. It just stays open. Not sure what is wrong since there are no errors being thrown and it seems to be working to some degree.

Here's all my code:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

if(!al_init())
{
    al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL,
                               "Failed to initialize Allegro!", NULL, NULL);
    return -1;
}

    display = al_create_display(640, 480);

if(!display)
{
    al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, 
                               "Failed to initialize display!", NULL, NULL);
    return -1;
}

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    ALLEGRO_FONT *pixFont = al_load_font("pixelated.ttf", 24, 0);

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

    al_draw_text(pixFont, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255), 50, 50, 0, "Hello World!");

    al_flip_display();

    al_rest(5.0);

    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like you, I got a blank window, but for some reason a second call to `al_flip_display` (right after the first) makes the background and text show up, so give that a try. Hopefully someone can explain this -- maybe its related to double buffering?

Comment: Tried it out but nothing changed.

Just stuck it right under the first call. 

Hopefully someone can figure tho out.